# How to scrape all links of products using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

There is a webpage and 42 products. I would like to get all links of 42 products to scrape individually them. But When I try to get them, I am getting only 16-20 of them.
I used two approaches:

1. I got page source using Selenium then scraped with BeautifulSoup
2. I only used selenium driver(css_selector, class_name) to get links.
   **The link need to scrape:** https://thrivecausemetics.com/collections/all?page=4&sort=ss_days_since_published%253Dasc

my 1st approach code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

webpage = "https://thrivecausemetics.com/collections/all?page=4&sort=ss_days_since_published%253Dasc"
driver.get(webpage)
time.sleep(15)

page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
links = [link['href'] for link in soup.find("ul", class_="grid-list").find_all('a', class_='tile-images')]
print(links)
print(len(links))
```

my 2nd approach

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
webpage = "https://thrivecausemetics.com/collections/all?page=4&sort=ss_days_since_published%253Dasc"
driver.get(webpage)
time.sleep(15)
ul_tag = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.grid-list")
print(ul_tag)
li_tags = ul_tag.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.grid-item.is-visible")
# print(li_tags)
print(len(li_tags))
```

All two approaches are helping to get all links. Using above codes, it is taking only 16 product links.

Any help is appreciate

Comment: Please read [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405791/what-should-a-minimal-reproducible-example-include-for-problems-with-automati)

Comment: Provide the links that you can successfully get and the links that are skipped.

Comment: While my answer fully solves your actual issue, I cannot help but feeling I need to make sure you actually want to **get that data**, as opposed to you actually wanting to **only use selenium**. If you really, only need a selenium based solution, please let me know and I will provide one.

Comment: Barry the Platipus, thanks for your answer, I tried that code on google colab, but I need only selenium based solution because of integration to the project. Please help me to solve using selenium

Comment: Ok @MukhammadErmatov, give me a few minutes

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I will mark and upvote if it helps me no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data is being pulled from an API endpoint by javascript, once the page loads, so requests cannot see it. The way forward is to scrape the actual API endpoint (you can find it in Dev tools - Network tab). Here is one way to obtain that data:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://b7i79y.a.searchspring.io/api/search/search.json?resultsFormat=native&page=1&resultsPerPage=500&sort.ss_days_since_published=asc&siteId=b7i79y'

r = requests.get(url)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['results'])
print(df)
```

This will display in terminal:

```
brand   collection_id   handle  id  imageUrl    intellisuggestData  intellisuggestSignature msrp    name    popularity  price   product_type_unigram    rating  ratingCount reviews_total_reviews   sku ss_available    ss_image_alt    ss_inventory_count  ss_name_type    tags    thumbnailImageUrl   uid url variant_id  variant_mfield_filter_color
0   Bigger Than Beauty Skincare [159254708314, 174020034650, 262184763482, 263320010842]    pumpkin-spice-latte-liquid-balm-treatment   bed045c1cec90548f830bfa4bc3e2e56    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/PSL_Component_1_medium.jpg?v=1662478574    eJxKMs80t6xkYGAICXM3NDZhMGQwZDBgMLdgSC_KTAEEAAD__1t7Bhw 5a3173ae3360eadabcc446e464c51a6269f0e28ab8d79b2be8b1da2b0f0201da    0   Pumpkin Spice Latte Liquid Balm Lip Treatment™  10669   26  treatment   4.45424 295 295 TVG134  1   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/PSL_Swatch_New_medium.jpg?v=1662478574 20060   lip treatment   [2261, 4522, 50, 800, Benefits:Hydrating, Benefits:Plumping, collection-badge::BACK IN STOCK!, collection::hide-variants, Face, Fill Size:&lt; 1 fl oz, linked::liquid-balm-set, lip plumper, lip plumping, plump, plumper, plumping, recommendation::all-skincare, Skin Concern:Dull and Dry Skin, swatches::show, travel size, Vegan] https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/PSL_Component_1_medium.jpg?v=1662478574    4742230212698   https://thrive-causemetics.myshopify.com/products/pumpkin-spice-latte-liquid-balm-treatment [32526428766298]    NaN
1   Thrive Causemetics  NaN dream-lash-duo  26b794e35fad33ba5496223db9f1bed4    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Mascara_LashSerum_PDPSets_medium.jpg?v=1659461093  eJxKMs80t6xkYGAICXM3NDZhMGQwYjBgMLdgSC_KTAEEAAD__1uGBh0 12ef5b3a76c62cc8e9d2b0f6f2b2341a3903bbc584f3c347b96f6b9d67f38c05    0   Dream Lash Duo  NaN 71  duo NaN NaN NaN NaN 1   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Mascara_LashSerum_PDPSets_nocopy_medium.jpg?v=1659491015   274 dream lash duo  [collection::hide-variants, YBlacklist] https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Mascara_LashSerum_PDPSets_medium.jpg?v=1659461093  6766529675354   https://thrive-causemetics.myshopify.com/products/dream-lash-duo    [40035119235162, 40035119267930, 40035119300698]    NaN
2   Thrive Causemetics  NaN liquid-lash-extensions-lash-serum   096bf1756363b494a31863ae20803818    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/LashSerum_Component_medium.jpg?v=1659566057    eJxKMs80t6xkYGAICXM3MrNgMGQwZjBgMLdgSC_KTAEEAAD__1wOBiY 5fa69eead6ac5da701c5be908298ba006e9490183a18de4e398e7599d0a01eb6    0   Liquid Lash Extensions™ Lash Serum  21949   56  serum   4.075   40  40  TVG268  1   NaN 75132   lash serum  [collection-badge::New!]    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/LashSerum_Component_medium.jpg?v=1659566057    6729553772634   https://thrive-causemetics.myshopify.com/products/liquid-lash-extensions-lash-serum [39909600854106]    NaN
3   Thrive Causemetics  [267668095066]  brilliant-face-highlighter-skin-perfecting-powder   9ff61df38853620f61d4c39e7363f5a2    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Brilliant-Face-Highlighter_Component_ToQuyen_medium.jpg?v=1657292791   eJxKMs80t6xkYGAICXM3MjJnMGQwYTBgMLdgSC_KTAEEAAD__1vKBiI 7d651c91af12c272ce4478e268a2764530f5df50b7a4a78817eaeda1251cd85b    0   Brilliant Face Highlighter™ Skin Perfecting Powder  12525   34  highlighter 4.18182 66  66  TVG227  1   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Brilliant-Face-Highlighter_Component_Shael_medium.jpg?v=1657292793 44920   highlighter [collection-badge::trending, Highlight, Highlighter, Highlighting]  https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Brilliant-Face-Highlighter_Component_ToQuyen_medium.jpg?v=1657292791   6729555247194   https://thrive-causemetics.myshopify.com/products/brilliant-face-highlighter-skin-perfecting-powder [39909605703770, 39909605736538, 39909605769306]    [gold]
4   Thrive Causemetics  NaN brilliant-face-set  dab6ca20bb4cf41740cacbbc37fb4f20    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Highlighter_BEB_Primer_Set_PDP_medium.jpg?v=1657585503 eJxKMs80t6xkYGAICXM3MjJnMGQwZTBgMLdgSC_KTAEEAAD__1vVBiM c0e8eb4abe31f0bd31324450909de60b570dafb73a7e5f6f4c3cb49e93b7a9e4    0   Brilliant Face Set  NaN 84  sets    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Highlighter_BEB_Primer_Set_V2_medium.jpg?v=1657585503  3889    brilliant face sets [collection-badge::New!, collection::hide-variants, ST-unpublished] https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Highlighter_BEB_Primer_Set_PDP_medium.jpg?v=1657585503 6765261324378   https://thrive-causemetics.myshopify.com/products/brilliant-face-set    [40031327682650, 40031327715418, 40031327748186, 40031327780954, 40031327813722, 40031327846490, 40031327879258, 40031327912026, 40031327944794, 40031327977562, 40031328010330, 40031328043098, 40031328075866, 40031328108634, 40031328141402, 40031328174170, 40031328206938, 40031328239706, 40031328272474, 40031328305242, 40031328338010, 40031328370778, 40031328403546, 40031328436314, 40031328469082, 40031328501850, 40031328534618, 40031328567386, 40031328600154, 40031328632922, 40031328665690, 40031328698458, 40031328731226, 40031328763994, 40031328796762, 40031328829530, 40031328862298, 40031328895066, 40031328927834]    NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
73  Thrive Causemetics  [27186779, 209907910, 237619142, 333714566, 399044812, 2738815001, 4013293593, 5575639065, 5575770137, 5575802905, 6686801945, 56789368922, 56833736794, 57405112410, 81244520538, 82036260954, 82769608794, 83615547482, 84961689690, 85599420506, 86598778970, 87577591898, 88078483546, 89189417050, 89505661018, 89797230682, 91221393498, 91755741274, 93260021850, 96613498970, 149781872730, 153671794778, 157076848730, 159474384986, 166734495834, 173874675802, 262216908890, 262273564762, 263767261274, 263970160730, 264544747610, 264579055706, 264579121242, 265485779034, 266068197466, 266346889306, 266381164634, 266457251930, 266889232474, 267015094362, 267954094170] triple-threat-color-stick   908b72d51839441d48d27fc251340e88    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/TCCS_Triple_Threat_Color_Stick_Isabella_V2_2db06b39-24da-4e68-8029-dab1f68a985e_medium.jpg?v=1601483873    eJxKMs80t6xkYGAICXM3NDVhMGQwN2EwYDC3YEgvykwBBAAA__9h-AZY    67aceb71cc8a5bfa95da136235f5c18504688f10daed921caa8efe7e75dcfa8d    0   Triple Threat™ Color Stick  35732   36  threat  4.42416 3171    3171    TVG154  1   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/TCCS_Triple_Threat_Color_Stick_Mieko_V2_e92bcbce-3708-4941-a23b-5122e9881820_medium.jpg?v=1601483873   164632  triple threat   [Benefits:Hydrating, Benefits:Waterproof, Best Sellers, blush, body, collection-badge::Multi-Use!, Coverage:Buildable, Finish:Dewy, Finish:Shimmer, Formulation:Cream, intl::ca, Lips, Lipstick, recommendation::face, shade-finder::thumbnails, Triple Threat Color Stick, TVG285, TVG286, TVG287, Vegan, YCRF_cheeks] https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/TCCS_Triple_Threat_Color_Stick_Isabella_V2_2db06b39-24da-4e68-8029-dab1f68a985e_medium.jpg?v=1601483873    5892103302  https://thrive-causemetics.myshopify.com/products/triple-threat-color-stick [32456620376154, 18635615622, 18635615558, 32456620310618, 32456620408922, 18635615430, 18635615686, 40078997586010, 40078998175834, 40078999191642]    [pink, gold, purple, red, peach]
74  Thrive Causemetics  [27186779, 209907910, 237619142, 343406086, 383763660, 2738815001, 4013293593, 6686801945, 6845464601, 57475530842, 81244487770, 81951588442, 82036260954, 82769608794, 83476283482, 83810091098, 86001451098, 86594289754, 86765207642, 88078483546, 91221393498, 93260021850, 93929963610, 94846025818, 149781872730, 151323705434, 157076848730, 159474384986, 162671919194, 166112591962, 263766736986, 264805384282, 266185965658, 267195973722]   infinity-waterproof-brow-liner  05a0b2ec067e0d40becc91a6d7ff10a9    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/BrowLiner_Component_Christina_medium.jpg?v=1637091941  eJxKMs80t6xkYGAICXM3MLRgMGQwN2UwYDC3YEgvykwBBAAA__9h7QZY    c25ffd3a46285a1f90da35783af2fb62d7900453d9fa7fbd7e288f8fd13b9f1d    0   Infinity Waterproof Eyebrow Liner™  39291   23  liner   4.49396 2235    2235    TVG018  1   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/BrowLiner_Component_Audrey_medium.jpg?v=1637091946 209279  brow liner  [Benefits:Waterproof, Coverage:Buildable, default_variant::2, Infinity Waterproof Brow Liner, Ingredients:Shea Butter, intl::ca, recommendation::eyes, shade-finder::thumbnails, Vegan, YCRF_eyes]  https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/BrowLiner_Component_Christina_medium.jpg?v=1637091941  781737155   https://thrive-causemetics.myshopify.com/products/infinity-waterproof-brow-liner    [2199676227, 39591112081498, 2199676163, 35014122444, 39591112343642]   [beige, red, brown, black, grey]
75  Thrive Causemetics  [27186779, 91101891, 5576228889, 81244487770, 174020034650] gift-card   15c74aab8aa83d300f8c66cdca7c1cb1    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/egift-card_1__2_medium.png?v=1659654650    eJxKMs80t6xkYGAICXM3MLRgMGQwN2MwYDC3YEgvykwBBAAA__9h-AZZ    7ba842c650d93f11c8936dfaf70818667c3b3024b44fc6688ee25874d0ccf019    0   eGift Card  NaN 25  card    5   11  11  NaN 1   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Thrive_PDP_GiftCard_medium.jpg?v=1659654650    -16399  gift card   [::hide-dropdown-swatch, collection::hide-variants, Gift Cards, image::no-swap, intl::ca, swag, YBlacklist] https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/egift-card_1__2_medium.png?v=1659654650    337553443   https://thrive-causemetics.myshopify.com/products/gift-card [12622098246, 782092871, 12622102150, 782092875]    NaN
76  Thrive Causemetics  [27186779, 237619142, 343406086, 389141580, 81244520538, 91755741274, 153671794778, 157076848730, 159474384986] jackie  4f5bf8da32c6904051e29c44b49a4516    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Jackie_Faux_Lashes_1_medium.jpg?v=1582596256   eJxKMs80t6xkYGAICXM3NDdiMGQwN2cwYDC3YEgvykwBBAAA__9iGwZb    3425b4b7cf441485cfbc7cc37da68ae40efbe65e842df16229f0c1c29b172b7d    0   Jackie Faux Lashes™ 150 26  lashes  4.85714 14  14  TVG172  1   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/PDP_lashes_jackie_1024x1024_1_medium.jpg?v=1582596246  827 faux lashes [Faux Lashes, recommendation::eyes, swatches::hide, Vegan, YCRF_eyes]   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Jackie_Faux_Lashes_1_medium.jpg?v=1582596256   334825111   https://thrive-causemetics.myshopify.com/products/jackie    [775766255] NaN
77  Thrive Causemetics  [27186779, 237619142, 343406086, 389141580, 81244520538, 91755741274, 157076848730, 159474384986]   robin   cfe488b97e5e61b13c3060260a920885    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Robin_Faux_Lashes_medium.jpg?v=1582233291  eJxKMs80t6xkYGAICXM3NDdmMGQwt2AwABHpRZkpgAAAAP__YjYGXQ  3b387d1b5edb7855f9d83403ddac5c5559ddac6a8ea440cde30447897896cfa6    0   Robin Faux Lashes™  130 26  lashes  4.9 10  10  TVG173  1   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/PDP_lashes_robin_1024x1024_7a28a8f4-b602-4049-9480-6eddb8e94944_medium.jpg?v=1582233282    2152    faux lashes [Faux Lashes, recommendation::eyes, swatches::hide, Vegan, YCRF_eyes]   https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0582/2885/products/Robin_Faux_Lashes_medium.jpg?v=1582233291  334825555   https://thrive-causemetics.myshopify.com/products/robin [775768027] NaN
78 rows × 26 columns
```

The actual XHR request is asking only for 12 products (and then continues to ask for more products, as you scroll the page). I went ahead and asked for 500 products (see url), to make sure I get them all.

Requests documentation:https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Also, pandas relevant documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

EDIT: And here is a solution based off Selenium/chromedriver. Setup is for linux/chrome/chromedriver, you can adapt to your own setup - just observe the imports, and the code after defining the browser/driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
actions = ActionChains(browser)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
url = 'https://thrivecausemetics.com/collections/all?page=4&sort=ss_days_since_published%253Dasc'
browser.get(url) 
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler"))).click()
    print('declined cookies')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button!')
t.sleep(2)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="dialog dialog-email"]'))).find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="icon close"]').click()
    print('dismissed 10% offer')
except Exception as e:
    print('no 10% offer, damn')
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="dialog dialog-country"]'))).find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="icon close"]').click()
    print('dismissed country popup')
except Exception as e:
    print('no country popup')
products = [x.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a') for x in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li[class="grid-item is-visible"]'))) if len(x.text) > 3]
print('Total items:', len(products))
for p in products:
    print(p.get_attribute('href'))
    print('______________')
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
declined cookies
dismissed 10% offer
dismissed country popup
Total items: 42
https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/brilliant-eye-brightener
______________
https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/liquid-lash-extensions-mascara
______________
https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/waterproof-eyeliner
______________
https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/sheer-strength-hydrating-lip-tint
______________
https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/infinity-waterproof-eyeshadow-stick
______________
https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/triple-threat-color-stick
______________
https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/infinity-waterproof-brow-liner
[...]
```

For Selenium documentation, please visit https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: Thank you for your full answer. It is really helpful for me and worked without problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
ul_tag = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".grid-list.text-.align- .grid-item.is-visible .tile-heading-lockup a")
print("Total products: ", len(ul_tag))
for product_link in ul_tag:
    print("Product link: ", product_link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Output:

Total products:  42

Product link:  https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/brilliant-eye-brightener

Product link:  https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/liquid-lash-extensions-mascara

Product link:  https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/waterproof-eyeliner

Product link:  https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/sheer-strength-hydrating-lip-tint

Product link:  https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/infinity-waterproof-eyeshadow-stick

Product link:  https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/triple-threat-color-stick

Product link:  https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/infinity-waterproof-brow-liner

Product link:  https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/instant-brow-fix-semi-permanent-eyebrow-gel

Product link:  https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/liquid-lash-extensions-lash-serum

Product link:  https://thrivecausemetics.com/products/buildable-blur-cc-cream-with-spf-35

and so on...

Comment: I don't know why but product name is returning None.

Comment: And I need only product link not product name could you look at please

Comment: check the updated code